# Firefox: User Authentication

Tags: firefox

I am running Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a custom certificate used for client authentication for a private website.

Now when I open this site very first time after importing the .p12 certificate, a window pop up titled as "User Identification Request", where I have to press OK or cancel.

Once I press OK then further invocation of this web page do not prompt.

Is there any way to disable this "User Identification Request" window?

**UPDATE 1:** Firefox saves client authentication information in a file named `ClientAuthRememberList.txt`. But I do not find any documentation to create such file before starting firefox.

**UPDATE 2:** I switched to chrome but surprisingly chrome do not have an option "remember me".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to disable this "User Identification Request" window?

As the user/owner of that browser, or as the supplier of that site without influence on the configuration of the user's browser?

- User/owner of the browser: theoretically, yes, but it's not how firefox is currently written (compare for example this [bugzilla bug discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1672061); you need to manually OK this once for it to end up in "Authentication Decisions")
- Not owner browser configuration: No, as that would pose a privacy problem (imagine a website could ask for your bank account number to be sent to it)